# Ionic angular google maps - click not work on the phone

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic and angular google maps (AGM).
The program works fine but on the phone, the click doesn't work (when i'm press the screen, nothing happens)

HTML code:

```
<ion-content>
  <agm-map (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)" [latitude]="location.lat" [longitude]="location.lng" [zoom]="location.zoom">

  </agm-map>
</ion-content>
```

I've already tried the: data-tap-disabled="true" like this:

```
<agm-map data-tap-disabled="true" (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)" ...>

</agm-map>
```

but it's not working in my case...

Answer (score 0):

Use `(tap)`. It will work as a click also.

Comment: Still it's not response in phone.
I'm use `<agm-map (tap)="add()" ... >` and `data-tap-disabled="true"` in parent div...

Comment: so it has a parent div with (tap) on it? But it doesn't fire when you tap on the map right?

Comment: There is too many problem with ionic,
nothing work as you expected.
Back to work with regular Angular...
Thanks anyway for the help!